# Initializing Switch Case

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm building a program using a grade report and I'm having trouble calculating my GPA using a switch case. I'm unsure why it isn't assigning the correct values. I would also like if there is a way to ask for the number of classes taken and then get the loop to perform that said number of times.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Grades
{ 
char Name[20];
int Hrs;
int ID;
char ClassName[20];
char Grade;
char ClassID[6];
};


int main ()
{
struct Grades Transcript[6];
int classCnt = 0;
int vHrs=0, vGPA=0, totalHours=0, totalPoints = 0;
char vGrade;
char vName[20], vCID[6], vClassName[20];

printf("Enter Students Name: ");
    fgets(vName, 20, stdin);

do
{   printf("\nEnter Class ID: ");
        fgets(vCID, 6, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        strcpy_s(Transcript[classCnt].ClassID, vCID);
    printf("Enter Class Name: ");
        fgets(vClassName, 20, stdin);
        strcpy_s(Transcript[classCnt].ClassName, vClassName);
    printf("Enter Class Hours: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &vHrs);
        Transcript[classCnt].Hrs = vHrs;
    printf("Enter Class Grade: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &vGrade);
        Transcript[classCnt].Grade = vGrade;
    classCnt++;
    fflush(stdin);
    totalHours+=vHrs;
    switch (vGrade) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a': 4*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b': 3*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c': 2*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd': 1*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f': 0; 
        break;
    default: printf("Invalid Grade");}
    totalPoints += vGrade;
    vGPA = (totalPoints/totalHours);
}while(classCnt<=5);



printf("********************************** Grade Report:        *************************************");

printf("\n%d\n", totalHours);
printf("%d\n", vGPA);
system("Pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression statement:

```
4*vHrs;
```

is certainly valid in C but it doesn't actually *do* anything <sup>(a)</sup>.

Perhaps you may want to assign it to something, such as with:

```
addPoints = 4 * vHrs;
```

(declaring `addPoints` beforehand, of course) and then use *that* to affect `totalPoints` later:

```
totalPoints += addPoints;
```

In terms of asking for a class count, you can use `scanf("%d",...)` to get an integer from the user and then just use that integer in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int num, count;

    printf ("Enter countdown value: ");
    scanf ("%d", &count);
    for (num = count; num > 0; num--)
        printf ("%d ", num);
    puts ("BLAST OFF");
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run being:

```
Enter countdown value: 10
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 BLAST OFF
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Even a statement like `42;` is valid, though useless. The reason this is allowed is because you can have side effects in expressions. The classic case, though not many learners immediately see this, is the venerable `i++;`.

This is an expression which gives you the current value of `i` (which you throw away unless you're using it somehow), then increments `i` as a side effect.

Comment: Wow. I completely forgot to that just leaving it as 4*vHrs does nothing.. I even wrote a note to myself on my calendar hanging above me... Haha. Thank you SO much for the help!

Comment: If i ever design a language, I will leave out the '++' feature. Hell there is a language named after that operator! which only a madman would ever use :-P :-)

Comment: @Aniket, when coders are forced to choose between `bigHonkinVariableName++` and `bigHonkinVariableName = bigHonkinVariableName + 1`, I suspect they'll choose the former :-)

Comment: why not this one? `bigHonkinVariableName += 1` :-) It explicitly states that you are trying to modify the variable

Answer (score 1):

```
case 'A':
    case 'a': 4*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b': 3*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c': 2*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd': 1*vHrs; 
        break;
    case 'F':
    case 'f': 0;
```

None of these lines have any effect on the program you've written. You might want to assign `3*vHrs`, `4*vHrs` etc to a variable and then do the calculations below. You probably meant `vHrs *= 3` or `vHrs *=4` or something like that?